# append elements into an array element

Tags: perl

In my Perl program, I am reading an email by decoding it, splitting it into an array. In the snippet below, I am reading the elements and appending it until I find 'Email' or 'Phone' or 'GoToAssist'.

```
75  while(!($plain[$j] =~ /[Email|Phone|GoToAssist]/)){     
76      $plain[$x] .= "&nbsp;" . $plain[$j];
77      $j++;
78  }
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 76, <GEN0> line 921.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at test.pl line 77, <GEN0> line 921.
```

The code was working properly previously, I have hardly changed anything. I am wondering what went wrong.

Comment: Have you checked if your data has changed?

Comment: Yes, I checked. Two elements were changed. But I had removed them using regex. It doesnt work with the previous data either.

Comment: If it was working previously and data JUST changed - it has to be that the regex is not working as expected in removing faulty parts of the changed data. I mean, I have no empirical evidence...but WHAT ELSE could it be, haha. Could we get and example entry?

Comment: `$plain[$j]` is undefined. We cannot help you to fix this unless you show your complete code. Also the regex `/[Email|Phone|GoToAssist]/` doesn't do what you intend. It uses a character class that matches any of the characters `A E G P T a e h i l m n o s t |`. You want just `/Email|Phone|GoToAssist/`.

Comment: Here is the code https://gist.github.com/3083791. It is working now for some reason! I wonder whats going on!

Answer (score 3):

Its not an error, its a warning.

You are getting this warning because `$plain[$j]` is undefined.

You can use following code to check if `plain[$j]` is defined or not before appending:

```
while(!($plain[$j] =~ /[Email|Phone|GoToAssist]/)){     
     if(defined $plain[$j]){
         $plain[$x] .= "&nbsp;" . $plain[$j];
         $j++;
     }
 }
```

If this doesn't help, do share some more code.

And as @Borodin pointed out, your regex is not doing what you probably want. But this is not related to your question.

Comment: Well, that actually worked! But when I commented these changes, it did work again! I dont know whats going on to be honest. You can find my code here: https://gist.github.com/3083791 You can see the commented statements line # 77 onwards. Thanks.

Comment: @rad are you sure you have used the same data which was giving error earlier?

Comment: @rad strange...anyways you can keep if-defined check to prevent future warnings....the string being appended cannot be undefined

Answer (score 0):

`$plain[$j]` is undef. Add some print statements to find out if `$j` is what you expect it to be. If it's wrong, then find out why it ends up with the wrong value. It it's right, find out why `$plain[$j]` ends up with the wrong value.

Comment: I tried that. It gave me the same errors followed by a million &nbsp;'s. Sorry.

Comment: print "plain[x] = '" . ( $plain[$x] || '' ) . "'\n" ; print "plain[y] = '" . ( $plain[$y] || '' ) . "'\n" ;

Comment: I am getting plain[j] = ''
and plain[x] has about a thousand &nbsp;'s

Comment: then $plain[$j] and $plain[$x] are not defined - look into the code which populates them